# Progress Dialog animation not showing?

Tags: android

I had it working fine...  I added some activities to my app and now the animation aspect of the Progress Dialog is not showing.  The Progress Dialog popup shows, but the little circle animated icon doesn't show.  Here's some notes:

1.) It doesn't work in any of the several activities in my app.  Any activity that uses the Progress Dialog popup no longer shows the animation.

2.) I made changes to the app, but not any of the activities or classes that use the Progress Dialog.

3.) It seems to be something specific to my phone (Moto X Pure) because it works fine on my wife's phone (LG G2).

I read several posts that seem to indicate that it could be a problem with my development option settings, but I don't see anything that looks incorrect.  I have Window Animation Scale, Transition Animation Scale and Animator Duration Scale all set to 1x.

Here's my code.  This is from my LoginActivity, but as I said, it doesn't work in other classes as well:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

  ... 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //finish();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

          ...

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

           ...

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Edit:

Also, I seem to be getting an unusual amount of errors.  Here's my LogCat output:

```
    08-04 20:37:04.656 21761-21761/online.tipme.app I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-04 20:37:04.702 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/ActivityThread: Application online.tipme.app can be debugged on port 8100...
08-04 20:37:04.704 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=19]
08-04 20:37:04.704 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/app/online.tipme.app-2/oat/arm64/base.odex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.706 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/online.tipme.app-2/lib/arm64
08-04 20:37:04.713 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.713 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-support-annotations-23.2.0_858aa537f7a6d51e4c718d577a873b96da103588-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.719 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.719 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.726 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.726 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_8-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.733 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.733 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_7-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.738 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.738 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_6-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.745 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.745 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_5-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.750 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.750 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_4-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.759 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.759 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_3-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.765 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.765 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_2-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.770 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.770 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_1-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.777 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.777 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-slice_0-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.781 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.781 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-internal_impl-23.2.0_5e4ee41384105e9948ae506dd5eff2c6aae29ebf-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.788 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.788 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.2.0_158966069f8a3867ecdead9c719a0d5b802abeaf-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.794 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.794 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.2.0_ec2c66a9230f7199936cb3abd7be38c355b0bf6c-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.800 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.800 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-com.android.support-recyclerview-v7-23.2.0_caadf0103029ddc76cc4fb924c8984b1e58eec96-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.806 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.806 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-com.android.support-design-23.2.0_e944fe6b62fe4c59186245a238c4f80c5d5ce603-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.811 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.811 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.2.0_c070370c0648b101163720f82b913cbda75b0577-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.817 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.817 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.2.0_a003b982988e746a36ca3a40899e647f59b088ab-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.825 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=20]
08-04 20:37:04.825 21761-21761/online.tipme.app E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/online.tipme.app/cache/slice-PayPal_MPL_41e4c9a9596a46d800358a44cf512c7e9452d9ac-classes.dex". Will use given name.
08-04 20:37:04.830 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/online.tipme.app-2/lib/arm64
08-04 20:37:05.311 21761-21776/online.tipme.app I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 02953e5, I64c525f392
                                                          Build Date                       : 10/14/15
                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.05.13.03
                                                          Local Branch                     : workspace2
                                                          Remote Branch                    : 
                                                          Remote Branch                    : 
                                                          Reconstruct Branch               : 
08-04 20:37:05.315 21761-21776/online.tipme.app I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-04 20:37:13.464 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:37:13.464 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:37:13.480 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:37:13.480 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:37:13.497 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:38:48.757 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:38:48.757 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:38:48.773 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:38:48.773 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:38:48.790 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:39:16.221 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:39:16.221 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:39:16.236 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:39:16.236 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
08-04 20:39:16.252 21761-21761/online.tipme.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit using XML files but the String values.

```
 TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id."id of string value");
```

In the String values:

```
<string name="developer">Developer: GamesExplosion</string>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.